# Why is voltage from sound card in audio circuit not constant?

Tags: audio, microphone

I have a [JLI2555](https://www.jlielectronics.com/content/JLI-2555BXZ3-GP.pdf) microphone capsule connected to a JFET Transistor that is then connected to a sound card that goes into the usb port of my laptop. The idea is that I want to record my voice using the microphone. The capsule and the JFET are powered by the sound card through a TRS Plug.

The circuit looks as [the above image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone)
[image]

The only difference is that the output is at V+ and there is no capacitor.

The TRS plug is connected to the JFET part of the circuit in [the following way](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/computer_microphone.php)

[image]
(The op amp represents the internal circuitry of the sound card)

The voltage of the sound card mic input has a voltage of about 2.85 volts. It is constant when I measure it with my multimeter, but when I connect it to the JFET and capsule it randomly drops to like 0.14 volts. It rises again later and drops again. When I speak into the mic the result is that I hear a buzzing noise and barely hear my own voice if at all.

Why does the voltage drops like this? Is it that the mic port does not have enough power to power a mic capsule like this?

Comment: So you have the capsule, and additional JFET? Or you are just using the internal JFET in the capsule? Is the capsule connected correctly to TRS plug? It is unclear what you really have done to connect the items together, versus the diagrams that show how they should be wired together.

Comment: The capsule is connected to the JFET because it does not have an internal JFET built in. The difference between my design and the first image is that the output is at V+ not the capacitor(I have no capacitor) (This is the place where the JFET is connected to the first pin of the TRS Plug). The ground of the JFET is connected to the last pin (ground) of the TRS PLug. The TRS Plug is then connected to the sound card that is then connected to the USB port

Comment: Please show a JLI2555 datasheet that does **not** have an internal JFET.

Comment: https://www.jlielectronics.com/content/JLI-2555BXZ3-GP.pdf

Comment: Weird, the data sheet seems to give all the specs for the whole circuit as if the FET and everything was included like on normal electret capsules. But then the next question is, which JFET you used and how you connected it. Maybe the JFET is connected wrong?

Comment: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/123874/MotorolaInc/BFW11/1. I know for a fact it does not have the JFET. I have connected the circuit also with an op amp and headphones and I hear my voice nicely. BUt when connecting it to a computer I need an external power source like a battery to work on a computer. The computer is for some reason unable to power the JFET. 
Another thing is that when I connect the first and last pin of the TRS plug that goes out of the sound card and has 2.85 volts to a 5 k resistor, the voltage across the resistor does not drop 2.85 volts but much less.

Comment: And Yes I am aware the JFET datasheet has a mistake when labeling drain source gate

Comment: Why choose this JFET, doesn't it have much larger current than suggested in mic data sheet? That JFET is intended for VHF frequencies.

Comment: Where in the mic datasheet does it list the curreng?

Comment: In the datasheet it only says to use a FET

Comment: Well you simply can't use any FET. Sorry I made a mistake, current is not in the data sheet but on JLI web page for that product. And also other electret mics with internal JFET only consume about 0.5mA and the JFET you are using has several mA when Vgs=0. If I am not mistaken, you simply have incorrect JFET for the job.

Comment: aha ok. I used it from a youtube video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoQu3XXIayc&ab_channel=DIYPerks. Jesus christ this is probably the solution it caused me so much headaches. Do you know what jfet i can use?

Comment: I am not going to watch that video just to find out which JFET it suggests. If I am not mistaken though, it does not suggest the BFW11 but 2N4416.

Comment: The guy in the shop suggested bfw11 as alternative because they dont have 2n4416. Can a  mosfet also be used?

Comment: BUT 2n4416 also has 10 mA

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a wrong JFET for the job. That JFET is used for VHF radiofrequency signals and has current rating of several milliamps at zero Vgs.

Normally electret mics with built-in JFETs are listed around 0.5mA bias current.

Comment: Do you know any such JFETS all i find are in the mA range?

Comment: All JFETS have more than 0.5mA

Comment: @LEXORAI Difficult, but MMBF5484 with additional 1 kohm between S and GND has a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit diagrams in the OP will not work. The DIY-Perks video shows that an external FET is required as does the data sheet for the JLI2555. The difference between the two is the DIY-PeRKs is a has a differential output, but the JLI2555 datasheet version is single ended.

[image: DIY-Perks][image: JLI2555 datasheet]

The FET used in the video is obsolete, but the 2N4416A is still available. There are suggested substitutes on DigiKey. DigiKey offers many JFETs that may function for your application. I haven't the time to look closer, but don't rush in. Study prospective datasheets an make an informed choice.

The TRS connection in the OP will not work. Follow the electronics and make an appropraite choice.